# Why is the C program giving weird output using Scanf?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm currently learning C programming and I have come across this weird output.

```
// Program will try functionalities of the scanf function
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char array[40];
    scanf("Enter your address: %39s",array);   //39 + 1/o null character at the end of the character array.
    printf("The address is : %s", array);
    return 0;
}
```

It should accept input address and output the same.

```
PS C:\Users\G\Documents\C programs> gcc scanff.c -o scanff -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
PS C:\Users\G\Documents\C programs> ./scanff
jhgjhg
The address is : ■   a
```

What is that black block? Could someone explain!
Thanks.

Comment: `array` indicates base address, so use either `%u` or `%p`  as `printf("%u", array);` usage of `scanf` is wrong use as `scanf("%s",array);`

Comment: @csavvy By address, I meant to output the string that I entered in the character variable and output the same. Not the address of the variable. Also, for arrays AFAIK we can use  scanf(%s, array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the format specifier correctly for the `scanf()` function and display the custom message using `printf()`.

Have a look at the following code:

```
// Program will try functionalities of the scanf function
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char array[40];
    printf("Enter your address: ");
    scanf("%39s",array);   //39 + 1/o null character at the end of the character array.
    printf("The address is : %s", array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the documentation of scanf again.
The format string should contain format specifications and non-format characters which are to be matched literally.
You seem to assume that you can prompt using `scanf()`, that's not correct.

You might have more success with this (untested) code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char array[40];
    printf("Enter your address: ");
    scanf("%39s",array);   //39 + 1/o null character at the end of the character array.
    printf("The address is : %s\n", array);
    return 0;
}
```

It is also good practive to check the result of the `scanf()` call to see whether the expected number of values was read. In your case, the value was probably 0 because the literal characters were not matched in your input. When a format specification isn't used, the value of the destination variable is unchanged (in this case undefined, as the array contains the bytes that happen to be on the stack where the variable is allocated.)

Comment: Hey, after using the code I'm only able to output the first set of characters. Like: `Enter your address 
:Qwerty ash asjdhjas hdkajs  
The address is : Qwerty`                  It is just outputting the first word and not the whole thing

Comment: @technextgen `scanf` will stop at the first newline (Enter key pressed)

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm inputting in a single line with spaces. Does scanf not recognize spaces?

Comment: @technextgen yes it does. This happens here: Your input `Foo Bar`. `scanf("%39s",array);` will read `Foo`, `printf(...` will print `Foo`, and then your program ends and nobody ever reads `Bar`.

Comment: Again, have a look at the man page for scanf (I must admit I didn't look very closely myself). The `%s` format reads a string up to next whitespace; if you want to read up to end of line you can either use `fgets()` or the format `%[^\n]`.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- You did not initialise `array` properly. It should be:

  `char array[40] = "";`
- You mixed up scanf and printf with this statement:

  `scanf("Enter your address: %39s",array);`

  It should be broken into:

  `printf( "Enter your address: " );`

  `scanf ("%39s", array);`

Comment: How does not initialising matter? Won't `scanf()` append a `NUL` terminator itself after writing the input to the array?

Answer (score 1):

From man page of [scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

`int scanf(const char *format, ...);`

**Reason for undefined output:**

> Each conversion specification in `format` begins with either the
> character '%' or the character sequence "%n$"

**Solution** : Change `scanf("Enter your address: %39s",array);` to `scanf("%39s",array);`