# Do...while in C to terminate a program

Tags: c, do-while

I am using do...while as a loop control in C language. I need to terminate the program when the user enters "99", else the user should guess the number to terminate the program, until then the program will run. Here is the code. I don't have any compiler error, but instead it prints the number 0 to the number the users entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{
    int num = 0;

    do {
        scanf("Enter the magic number to terminate this program: %d\n", &num);

        printf("You entered : %d\n", num);

        num++;

    } while (num != 100);

    printf("\nThe magic number is correct and the program is terminated:");

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please change `scanf("Enter the magic number to terminate this program: %d\n", &num);` to `printf("Enter the magic number to terminate this program:\n"); scanf("%d", &num);` You can't include an output message in `scanf`.

Comment: Your scanf call is demanding that the user enter "Enter the magic number to terminate this program: "

Comment: You have a typo in scanf

Comment: If after your scanf() num is still at the init value 0, then it is important to know the return value of scanf() and check that it indcates successful read of a single value according to format string.

Comment: What is the input precisely? Did you try the full "Enter the magic number to terminate this program: 99 " as input? I just tried, it works and gets the output `You entered : 99

The magic number is correct and the program is terminated:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the C program giving weird output using Scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072754/why-is-the-c-program-giving-weird-output-using-scanf)

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` is not like Python's `input`, for example. It requires the exact input that you specify in the format string. In your particular case, you are expecting the users to enter "Enter the magic number to terminate this program: ", followed by a number.

One way to check this is to use the return value, which tells you the number of matched arguments:

```
k = scanf("...\n", &num);
printf("scanf managed to get %d inputs\n", k);
```

The solution is to split the input and output portions:

```
printf("Enter the magic number to terminate this program: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
```

`scanf` will automatically filter out whitespace between inputs, including the newlines that the user enters. You can also consume those explicitly with either `"%d\n"` or equivalently `"%d "`. However, you shouldn't do that. `scanf` treats any whitespace characters as "any number of whitespace", and will block until it receives the next non-whitespace character. It will also cause a problem if your stream ends without a trailing newline.

Comment: I would move the newline from the `scanf` to the `printf`. Function `scanf` will filter any leading whitespace, and the final `\n` will block its action.

Comment: @WeatherVane. No, yes, no: https://ideone.com/aa95Sa. OP's intent was to get input on the same line, good point about scanf filtering whitespace, but it will consume the \n just fine. Updating answer now

Comment: @WeatherVane. Updated. Also suers->users. I love autocorrect and mobile in general

Comment: Thanks. My tests will not input `99` until the *second* occasion, due to the (anyway unnecessary) newline in `scanf` format string. `scanf` filters leading whitespace, and most "kludges" are not needed.

Comment: @WeatherVane. Understood. Will update again. Forgot that not input is newline terminated

Comment: @WeatherVane. Updated. Really, the entire question is a duplicate

Comment: Thanks, but even the trailing space is blocking input here. `"%d"` is simple and enough.

Comment: The problem with trailing whitespace in the `scanf` format (whether newline or space does not matter) is that it represents an *indefinite number* of whitespace bytes.  `scanf` will thus continue to try to scan whitespace at that position until it sees non-whitespace, which is unwanted here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. Thank you for clarifying that. I've made what is hopefully my final update.

Comment: @WeatherVane. Finally understood what you were saying and wrote it down. Thanks for bearing with me :)